# How to create gnome-terminal as a child process of my process

Tags: linux, process, gnome, gnome-terminal

I've used `electron` to create desktop application on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop and used `spawn` in `child_process` to create child process. However, when I tried to create `gnome-terminal`, its parent process is not `electron` according to pstree.

My code is:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
spawn("gnome-terminal");
```

According to pstree,

```
init───lightdm───lightdm───init───gnome-terminal
```

Expected result:

```
init───lightdm───lightdm───init───bash───npm───sh───node───electron───electron───electron───gnome-terminal
```

Comment: Is it important to use gnome-terminal? Is it important to get the 'expected result'? Are you willing to try a work-around?

Comment: @sudodus I think so. I'm expecting to have the terminal as the child process of electron.

Comment: As a workaround you can try another terminal emulator. `xterm` and `sakura` will create separate processes for each instance. Both can be installed from the repository `universe` (and I think `xterm` comes with the installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). `xterm` is an old Unix tool. `sakura` is a modern tool.